# Filter by nested subdocument value with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I filter by a nested subdocument value ? 
I need to filter the playlist by the owner id.

```
var playlistSchema = new Schema();
playlistSchema.add({
    name: String,
    owner: {
        id: String,
        email: String,
        name: String
    }
});
```

Comment: Owner id in which order?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **sort()** method for filter by ascending order and descending order.

Ascending order use follow method.

```
playlist.find().sort('owner.id': 1);
```

Descending order use follow method.

```
playlist.find().sort('owner.id': -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume a collection sales has the following documents:

```
{
   _id: 0,
   items: [
     { item_id: 43, quantity: 2, price: 10 },
     { item_id: 2, quantity: 1, price: 240 }
   ]
}
{
   _id: 1,
   items: [
     { item_id: 23, quantity: 3, price: 110 },
     { item_id: 103, quantity: 4, price: 5 },
     { item_id: 38, quantity: 1, price: 300 }
   ]
}
{
    _id: 2,
    items: [
       { item_id: 4, quantity: 1, price: 23 }
    ]
}
```

The following example filters the items array to only include documents that have a price greater than or equal to 100:

```
db.sales.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         items: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$items",
               as: "item",
               cond: { $gte: [ "$$item.price", 100 ] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```